# Can anything be done to highlight non-syntax questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

As the private beta starts, there are so many questions about syntax that I want to weep.  Many of these questions are borderline unanswerable.  Wadler's Law notwithstanding, if the site continues to be overwhelmingly about syntax, it's going to drive me away from the private beta mighty quick.

Can anything be done to make non-syntax questions rise up to the top?

Is it OK for me to downvote a syntax question just because I think that flooding the site with such questions is not good for the site's long-term prospects?

Comment: Lots of syntax questions are getting asked right now because those are some of the most debated ones; they come to mind first and don't take much thinking to write questions and answers on. As time goes on I'm expecting we'll start getting more complex questions and more about implementation, optimization, and technical stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter questions to exclude ones tagged [syntax](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax). Just type `-[syntax] is:question` in the search bar.

You should downvote questions based on their quality or suitability for the site. Syntax is an important part of language design so if there is a well-written and otherwise on-topic and high-quality syntax question, please refrain from downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the “Ignore tag” button on the [tag page](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax). It's also present in the pop-up that appears when you hover the mouse on a tag. Then [change the setting of ignored tags to be hidden rather than grayed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-do-i-hide-posts-matching-my-ignored-tags/321052#321052) by going to the front page, clicking the “edit” button in the “Ignored Tags” box and changing the radio button from “Gray out …” to “Hide …”. That way you won't have to wade through these questions on the front page or in search results.

Unfortunately that only helps you, it doesn't help the site quality. What does help the site quality is to downvote and vote to close these questions. During the private beta, everyone can vote to close, and everyone with prior nontrivial Stack Exchange participation can downvote questions. Of course you should only downvote questions that should be downvoted and only vote to close questions that should be closed, but that is the case for most syntax questions (they're bikeshedding — no effort, and too broad or opinion-based, generally both).